# Parsing 64-bit int on appspot.com different then on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When you try to parse a 64-bit integer in JavaScript (`parseInt("5838406743490560")`) it works on the localhost server but not on the Appspot.com server. On the appspot.com server you need to parse it as a string instead of a `int64`.  Does anyone know why that is?

On localhost I can do this:

```
type Entity struct {
    List []*Message `json:"list"`
}

type Message struct {
    Id int64 `json:"id" datastore:"-"`
}
```

After uploading it to appspot.com, I need to parse it as a string or I get the error message below.

```
type Entity struct {
    List []*Message `json:"list"`
}

type Message struct {
    Id int64 `json:"id,string" datastore:"-"`
}
```

Package that gets sent where `id=parseInt("5838406743490560")`:

```
[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"gapiRpc","method":"service.datastore.delete","apiVersion":"v0","params":{"list":[{"id":5838406743490560}]}}]
```

- On Appspot.com I can not unmarshal using `json:"id" datastore:"-"`.
- On localhost it works perfect.

Error on Appspot.com only:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int64",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "badRequest",
     "message": "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int64"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

I am using SDK v1.9.6.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all, add some code and explain it better or tell us what you're doing.

Comment: I assumed sending int64 to a appengine server would be trivial to understand. But I will make a example.

Comment: All data is sent processed as `[]byte`, it's your job to convert it to whatever data type you want.

Comment: look at my edit please exact same code `parseInt("123456")` just switch from localhost:8080 to uploading it to ...appspot.com

Comment: where is parseint, how are you sending the data to the server? what is the error?

Comment: see edit, I added a error message

Comment: I upvoted your question, but I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: ok thanks, if somebody can confirm it I will report it as a bug at google, just want to make sure it is a bug or not.

Comment: The issue is because you are NOT marshaling the `id` you think you are. The id of type int64 is deeper in the JSON body. Your struct is trying to unmarshal the `id` key containing "gapiRpc". You need to embed a substruct to get the id from the params key.

Comment: no it is not, I will add the second list capsulating the message struct. Also if that was the case localhost would not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My localhost is running on a 64bit environment and appspot.com on a 32bit. All numbers smaler then 2147483647 parse ok, but although defined as int64 the id 5838406743490560 is to big to fit into 32bit therefore it get parsed as a string on a appspot.com instance.

Comment: This is a good lesson to check on the details of hosted services so you know their capabilities and limitations.  :)